# Выбор города с использованием SuggestView

Tags: javascript

Есть простой скрипт с использованием SuggestView от Яндекса. При вводе города в поле, под ним всплывают подсказки с адресом. Как сделать так, чтобы в подсказках были только горда? Без регионов, без улиц, без номеров домов, просто города.

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" name="adress" value="" id="city" class="city" placeholder="Город" autocomplete="off">
```

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
  var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('city');
}
```

Можете также предложить другие варианты, если они просты в использовании.
Честно искал и пробовал разные варианты, в том числе с чатом gpt, удивительно но не нашел простого варианта.